# Error de referencia a componente crdb_adoplus.dll Visual Studio 2012 - VB.NET - Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, crystal-reports

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en VB.NET en el cuál tengo que generar distintos reportes con Crystal Reports.

A la hora de ejecutar la aplicación me salta este error:

> file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll

Estuve averiguando y con esta porción de código insertada en la App.config ya no me da ese error:

`useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy = "true"`

Tambien utilicé otra solución que es crear la carpeta **dotnet1** manualmente e insertar el componente `crdb_adoplus.dll` dentro de ella y cambiar la App.config por esto:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy = "true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2. 0. 50727"></supportedRuntime>
 </startup>
```

Cualquiera de estas soluciones hace que mi proyecto corra sin errores en mi PC pero, a la hora de pasar el ejecutable a otra PC conectada por red esta solución no es factible.

Alguien sabe a qué se debe y si hay otra forma de reparar este error para que mi aplicación funcione correctamente en cualquiera de las PC que tengo conectadas por RED?

Desde ya muchas gracias, Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución y es trabajar con un **framework .net 2.0** en el proyecto de windows forms ya que crystal reports trabaja con dicha versión de framework.

Editar la **App.config** solo va hacer que el proyecto corra en la máquina donde se está trabajando. Para que dicho proyecto pueda correr en todas las máquinas clientes se debe trabajar con un **framework 2.0**